# php make function inside a variable

Tags: php, string, function

Im sure I have seen an implementation of this in PHP somewhere and I am positive if it exists its a PHP 5 thing. Any way I was wondering if it was possible to set and run a function from a string and set the returned value to the value of the string. e.g.

```
<?php $hi = function(){ return "Hello World"; }; 
echo $hi(); ?>
```

It probably is not possible but please post anything similar.

Comment: Upon rereading the question I've become unsure about what you're asking. Can you provide an example program and expected result?

Comment: I have edited my post to hopefully illustrate my needs. Is there any way I could use this in the context of a class e.g being able to access $this etc...

Comment: This should work as-is in PHP 5.3. You can use variables of the parent scope by explicitly including them in the function using the `use` syntax. See the manual page I linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous functions were introduced in PHP 5.3.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

This is the most recent version, which you may not have installed yet.